# org-crypt fails with Error: (error “Encrypt failed”)

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to encrypt entries with org-crypt, but I get this unhelpful error message:

> No crypt key set, using symmetric encryption. Error: (error "Encrypt
>   failed")

It correctly recognizes that I want symmetric (i.e. passphrase) encryption, but doesn't ask for one, and fails instead.

For reference: if I run `epa-encrypt-file` I do get a dialog for passphrase entry in the minibuffer.

This is the relevant config:

```el
(require 'epa-file)
(require 'org-crypt)
(epa-file-enable)

(setq epa-pinentry-mode 'loopback)

;;; (setenv "GPG_AGENT_INFO" nil)

(org-crypt-use-before-save-magic)

(setq org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance (quote ("crypt")))

;;; GPG key to use for encryption

;;; Either the Key ID or set to nil to use symmetric encryption.
```

Edit: this is the stack trace - still not very informative...

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Encrypt failed")
  signal(error ("Encrypt failed"))
  error("Encrypt failed")
  org-encrypt-entry()
  org-scan-tags(org-encrypt-entry (lambda (todo tags-list level) (progn (setq org-cached-props nil) (or (and (member "crypt" tags-list))))) nil)
  org-encrypt-entries()
  run-hooks(before-save-hook)
  basic-save-buffer(t)
  save-buffer(1)
  funcall-interactively(save-buffer 1)
  call-interactively(save-buffer nil nil)
  command-execute(save-buffer)
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question both here and on SO. Choose one place (I suggest this one) and delete the question from the other.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce the problem. Also, the `Encrypt failed` error is signaled not by `org-crypt` itself but from the `epg` library it uses, specifically from `epg-encrypt-string`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to ask emacs to break and dump a trace when the error happens?

Comment: See [Debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging)

Comment: Probably the first thing to try is to set `debug-on-error` to `t` and see if you get a backtrace.

Comment: Part of the problem with the uninformative backtrace is that you probably have a compiled `epg` library loaded and the debugger cannot get much information out of it. Try `(load-library "epg.el")` to load the uncompiled library and see if the backtrace gives you any more detail.